# Django is not sending POST request

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am building a simple web app with Django and got into this weird situation. I want to delete an entry of a model but the html won't send any post request.

**delete.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p> Are you sure to delete "{{obj}}" ?</p>
        <a href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}">GO BACK </a>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**View for delete.html in views.py**

```
def delete_room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        room.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'base/delete.html', {'obj':room})
```

**Model in models.py**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # participants =
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('room/<str:pk>', views.room, name='room'),
    path('create-room/', views.create_room, name='create-room'),
    path('update-room/<str:pk>', views.update_room, name='update-room'),
    path('delete-room/<str:pk>', views.delete_room, name='delete-room'),

    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

I've tried sending POST request from other templates and it woorks fine like adding new rooms and updating existing ones.
When I click on Confirm, it shows nothing in terminal.

Comment: What do you want to show in the terminal?  Try `print(request.POST)` to see what is being sent.  Is the room being deleted?  Check the admin.

Comment: I guess you need to specify   action  url ,    action="<the_url_to_delete>".   Also its better to to use  'DELETE' method instead of 'POST'.

Comment: I am not printing anything. I want to delete an entry from the database in the Room model.

Comment: The room is not deleted and this is the request body: <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: I think the problem is with the template _delete.html_ . I don't receive any post request when I click on Confirm. @Jisson

Comment: The code you have shown in your question worked perfectly for me.  The problem is elsewhere.  I'd need to see more of your code to troubleshoot where the error is.

Comment: you will have to pass the PK in the URL you are calling to delete the object, how are you doing that when you click the button? because your action is empty, so if there is already a URL where PK is being passed then it should be okay, else you can explicitly pass the url in the action itself.

Comment: How do I pass the URL in action? I am new to Django :) let's say if the url of the post that i'm deleting is delete-room/1. should I update the action like this: action = 'dalete-room/1'?

Comment: Does it delete the post and update the html page? @raphael

Comment: It does delete the post (assuming one exists, otherwise you will get an error).  and then redirects to `'home'`.  If I see your code, or perhaps a Github of it, I might be able to spot the problem you are having.  Best of luck.